# correct name of the files in the layers panel

Tags: pyqgis

I wrote a script for clipping all the raster files in a directory using a polygon shapefile. The script works fine, but the clipped layers are then uploaded in QGIS with the generic name Clipped (mask).

How can I do to preserve the correct name of the original files.

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import *

raster_filepath = "R:\\S1\\Season_2014_2015\\1_splitted\\VV"

mask_filepath = "R:\\RRE-    GIS\\Vector\\Border_scenes\\Rothamsted\\Rothamsted_box.shp"
mask_layer = QgsVectorLayer(mask_filepath, 'mask', 'ogr')

outputDir = "R:\\S1\\Season_2014_2015\\1_splitted\\VV"

# create the new folders clip
dirCreateClip = outputDir + "\\" + "clip"

if not os.path.exists(dirCreateClip):
    os.makedirs(dirCreateClip)

for i in os.listdir(raster_filepath):

    layercount = os.path.join(raster_filepath, i)  
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(layercount, 'raster')

    fileOut = dirCreateClip + "\\" + i
    fileOutClip = fileOut[:-4] + "_clip.tif"

    processing.runandload("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", \
    raster_layer, \
    mask_layer, \
    None, \
    False, \
    True, \
    True, \
    5, \
    4, \
    75, \
    6, \
    1, \
    False, \
    0, \
    False, \
    "", \
    fileOutClip)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this has been changed in the recent versions of QGIS (I'm still using 2.18.2) but you could try not loading the output file using `processing`. Instead load it with `iface.addRasterLayer()` so that you can give it any name you like (or the name of the file). So you could:

1. Replace `processing.runandload()` with `processing.runalg()`.
2. After the `processing` algorithm, use something like `iface.addRasterLayer(fileOutClip, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fileOutClip))[0])`

So your final loop could be like:

```
for i in os.listdir(raster_filepath):
    layercount = os.path.join(raster_filepath, i)  
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(layercount, 'raster')
    fileOut = dirCreateClip + "\\" + i
    fileOutClip = fileOut[:-4] + "_clip.tif"

    processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", \
    raster_layer, \
    mask_layer, \
    None, \
    False, \
    True, \
    True, \
    5, \
    4, \
    75, \
    6, \
    1, \
    False, \
    0, \
    False, \
    "", \
    fileOutClip) 

    iface.addRasterLayer(fileOutClip, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fileOutClip))[0])
```

Comment: @ilFonta - Most welcome! Glad it worked :)